# Breeze EF default values set server side for EF object overwritten by Breeze

Tags: entity-framework, breeze

We have some partial classes implemented server side that override the ef object constructors and provide default values to a set of fields.  It seems by the time Breeze gets a hold of the object graph it is going around and trashing those default values.  Is there a setting to tell Breeze to only update the values of the EF objects when they are dirty or otherwise have seen a change on the client?

Workarounds: We are working to hide those fields from Breeze by inheriting then manipulating the EFContextProvider but it feels yucky and is a bit ugly.  We also want to avoid setting all of these defaults in the client because we have other interfaces not using Breeze that allows us to keep this behavior server side and easy to share....

Thank you for noodling on this awesome people!

MORE INFO: 
Entity Framework is tracking a class, say Vehicle.  In this case we want to tap into the default constructor of that class to provide some default values for like, IsValid=true, IsInStock=true,StockItemNumber=1123123,blah...  just stuff that the Client will never be a part of and need not manage.

When Breeze reads the metadata and finds these properties it overwrites these initialized values on save and resets them back to their null values.

It feels nasty to deal with this on the server by 'hiding' the properties from the Breeze metadata and since it seems Breeze is quite aware if a particular field is 'dirty', what about just not messing with a given field if it knows for fact it was never touched.  I am sure there is a fantastic answer to do this, or a great reason someone else thought up why its a terrible idea !  tnx, -J

Comment: Can you give a little more detail? Still not exactly sure what you are describing.

Comment: I added a little more info above.  I have also come across another example that can perhaps better explain.  When reading the RavenDB spec I see this term 'Patch'.  It is best described here [link](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.5/http-api/http-api-single#patch) and talks about a process where 'changes' are merged into the entity based only on those fields that were 'modified' vs. the entire entity being written.